# Paradox: Is the derivative of this function continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, continuity

\begin{equation}
h(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})&\text{ if } x\neq 0\\
0&\text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Is the derivative of $h(x)$ continuous at $x = 0$?

How about the derivative of $k(x) = xh(x)$?

---

When I tried to differentiate it directly, the $\cos(1/x)$ in the result suggests that the limit of $h'(x)$ when $x\rightarrow 0$ does not exist.

However, when I use the definition to calculate the derivative, it shows that the derivative is $0$ when $x\rightarrow0$.

Which one is correct?

Comment: This means that the function is differentiable but not continuous differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

Both are. For $x \ne 0$, we have 
$$ h'(x) = 2x \sin\frac 1x - \cos \frac 1x $$
so $\lim_{x\to0} h'(x)$ does not exist. On the other hand 
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{h(x) - h(0)}x = \lim_{x\to 0 } x\sin \frac 1x = 0 $$
that is $h'(0) = 0$. So $h$ is differentiable with 
$$ h'(x) = \begin{cases} 2x \sin \frac 1x - \cos \frac 1x, & x \ne 0\\ 0 & x =0 \end{cases}
 $$ 
which is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying concepts